# Forgot Password script PHP mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, email, mysqli

Hi I am trying to make a script forgot password so when user enter email in it it will verify that if entered email matches the database email if yes then sends confirmation email to his email address.
      It was working fine untill I was using mysql but after converting it to mysqli it not working. When user enter email in it it does't send email or even it doesn't echo that email sent or no errors.

**Here is my Forgot.php script** (UPDATED SCRIPT *AGAIN*)

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(0);
    if($_POST['submit']=='Send') {
        //keep it inside
        $email=$_POST['email'];

        $con=mysqli_connect("lovehost","root","123","user");
        // Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
        $query = mysqli_query($con,"select * from login where user_email='$email'") or die(mysqli_error($con)); 

        $numrows = $query->num_rows();                                  

        if ($numrows == 1) {  
            $code=rand(100,999);
            $message='You activation link is: http://bing.fun2pk.com/forgot.php?email=$email&code=$code';
            mail($email, "Subject Goes Here", $message);
            echo 'Email sent';
        } else {
            echo 'No user exist with this email id';
        }
    }
?>
<form action="forgot.php" method="post">
    Enter you email ID: <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: just check the value of $numrows

Comment: I agree with Rishabh. The issue does seem to lie with the num rows.
I had a problem with the ->num_rows() command aswell. Perhaps use a sql limit or try the Procedural style: mysqli_num_rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think u should use 
mysqli_num_rows ($query) method inside your if condition to check if email exist or not.

for example:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows ($query)==1)
{
//your mail method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly then `$_GET['ID']` is not set, because you submit the form to `forgot.php` without a GET value named ID

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix this using a test in my website and your codes should be like this
even that there are a lot of bugs and your database can easily get 'hacked' by anonymous users still just to show the problem.
**Forgot.php**

```
<?php 
    error_reporting(0);
    require('includes/db.php');
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $code = rand(100,999);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email = '$email'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($count == 1) {
            mysql_query("update users set activation_code='$code' where email='$email'");
            //That Mail code should be put here    <----------------------
        } else {
        }
        echo " Something Here for a response";
    }
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    Enter you email ID: <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

This worked after I tested :/